# Taylor expansion in complex analysis. Why $f(z)=\operatorname{Log} (z+1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

$f(z)=\text{log} 2+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \left( \dfrac{z}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2} \right)^n.$

Why $f(z)=\operatorname{Log} (z+1)$ at $|z-1| < 2 $ ?

At $|z-1|<2,$ $\operatorname{Log} (z+1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} z^n.$

But why this is equal to $f(z)$ ?

I don't know how should I deformate $f(z)$ or $\text{Log} (z+1).$

Comment: Hint: $$
\log (z + 1) = \log \left( {2\frac{{z + 1}}{2}} \right) = \log 2 + \log \left( {\frac{{z + 1}}{2}} \right) = \log 2 + \log \left( {1 + \frac{{z - 1}}{2}} \right).
$$ Now use the standard Taylor series with $(z-1)/2$ in place of $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have$\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}$
$$\Log(1+u)=\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{u^n}n,\quad u\in\mathbf C, |u|<1.$$
Now set $\dfrac{z-1}2=u:\quad |u|<1\iff |z-1|<2$, and therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \Bigl( \dfrac{z-1}{2} \Bigr)^n=\Log\Bigl(1+\frac{z-1}2\Bigr)=\Log\frac{z+1}2=\Log(z+1)-\Log 2.$$

Comment: Does $\text{Log}(a)+\text{Log}(b)=\text{Log}(ab)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ hold ?

Comment: As far as I remember, it works  for a given determination of the complex logarithm , if one of $a,b$ is a positive real number.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $|z-1|<2$. Then we can write $z=1+2u$ where $|u| < 1$, so that $\frac{z}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=u$. Thus $f(z)=\log{2}+\log(1+u)=\log(2+2u)=\log(1+z)$.